# Fedora remix costumization

Tags: linux

I am making a USB live image based on fedora 16 to be used by my students in the bioinformatics class, but, so far and from what i've seen, you cannot chroot into a fedora live image directory before it is compressed to an image file (i have checked https://kororaa.org/ and http://www.montanalinux.org/fedora-remix-howto-screencast.html ). Everything is setted up in the ks files of kick-start, the proble is that i would like to add some extra software, that it's only available to me as binaries and cannot be found in RPM form.

I have thought to make RPM files from this binaries, but without any success (i have followed this http://www.losurs.org/docs/tips/redhat/binary-rpms and a few modifications, having the all files in the tar.gz and copying them to the BUILDROOT directory on %install section).

Basically i'm stuck. I would appreciate any help, on editing the ks files so that i can put binary files directly in the image directory while it's beeing created or making a RPM file from these binary files.

Thanks in advance,
SwatchPuppy

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the image and cp -r all the contents elsewhere, and then re-make the image after adding your packages?

Comment: Are you saying that i can mount the live image created, chroot or copy all the software that i want into the image and then re-make the image? Can you tell me the commands to remake the image after it has been changed?